# WebLogic Server 11g with java based node manager stdout/stderr log path configuration

Tags: rhel5, weblogic

How I can configure the path where the stdout logs are written by the WebLogic server?

I've read about `-Dweblogic.log.RedirectStdoutToServerLogEnabled=true`, but this redirects only part of the output. For example if I will run a thread dump, the output will remain in the original log file.

I think it should be an option in `nodemanager/startup.properties` file.

WebLogic version is 10.3.2.0 and I am using a java based node manager. OS is RHEL 5.

Thank you,
Mircea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the logs can be redirected to standard WebLogic logging with `-Dweblogic.log.RedirectStdoutToServerLogEnabled=true` See: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/logging/config_logs.html#wp1022848 and http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/logging/RedirectJVMOutput.html this can also be configured from the WL Admin Console by ticking the `Environment/Servers/<server_name>/Logging/Advanced/Redirect stdout logging enabled` checkbox.

Other application logs can be managed by WebLogic logging system or by log4j.

The native java output (like thread dumps) goes to the log configured at the domain creation and set by the NodeManager at the startup time of the ManagedServer. The location is `$DOMAIN_HOME/servers/<server_name>/logs/<server_name>.out` See: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13740/overview.htm#i1079068
This log is not rotated by WebLogic and should be rotated by something like logrotate.